# Titanium Appcelerator Ti.storekit (3.0.2). missing appleincrootcertificate.cer missing

Tags: ios7, appcelerator-titanium, storekit

I am trying to implement **Ti.storekit** for my application. I have some requirement of InApp purchase.

I am using **Titanium 5.2.2** version. and for **Ti.Storekit 3.0.2**.

But, I am getting issue everytime.

**appleincrootcertificate.cer is missing.**

Answer (score 1):

Answer from [documentation](https://github.com/appcelerator-archive/ti.storekit/blob/master/ios/documentation/index.md) :

1. Download the Apple Inc. Root Certificate ([link](http://www.apple.com/appleca/AppleIncRootCertificate.cer))
2. Add the AppleIncRootCertificate.cer to your app's `Resources` folder.